# NgbModule.forRoot() giving error "Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof NgbModule'.ts"

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I want to add Bootstrap modal to my Angular Project. So I installed ng bootstrap using "npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" and then bootstrap using "npm install bootstrap@4.5.2".

When I add this sentence "NgbModule.forRoot()" under imports in app.module.ts it gives an error "Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof NgbModule'."

I however tried to remove forRoot() and imported only NdbModule and ran my application. But it gives the following error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY24j.png)

When I searched online about how to remove the above error, the solution I got is to add forRoot(). But it is giving error "Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof NgbModule'."

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'appBootstrap';
  
  closeResult: string;
  
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}
    
  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }
  
  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return  `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }
}
```

login.component.html:

```
<h1>Modal Popup Example</h1>
   
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(mymodal)">Open My Modal</button>
   
<ng-template #mymodal let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Bootstrap Modal</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    This is a sample modal
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">Ok</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testproject</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Angular Version:
Angular CLI: 8.0.6
Node: 12.19.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.0.3

This is the first time I am posting a question in Stackoverflow. Please suggest if I missed any details.

Comment: What version of ngBoostrap are you using?

Comment: from (I think remember) ng-bootstrap 4.0.0 it's not use forRoot(). The actual version of ng-bootstrap is the 8.0.0

Comment: Angular: 8.0.0  Bootstrap: 4.5.2  I installed ng bootstrap using "npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap", so the version should be the latest one which 8.0.0

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue while trying to install bootstrap for my angular project created using angular/cli

I followed the 'manual installation' method mentioned in https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started
(Click on the link "Click here to hide detailed instructions" for step by step instructions)

The main thing is checking the dependencies - [ng bootstrap dependencies](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started#dependencies)

---

Explanation of what I did:

1. As mentioned here([ng bootstrap dependencies](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started#dependencies)), for Angular 10, the dependencies are `ng-bootstrap - 8.x.x` and `Bootstrap CSS - 4.5.0`

   ```
   npm install bootstrap@4.5.0
   npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@8.0.0
   ```

   **Note:** Use `--legacy-peer-deps` switch if you get dependency errors
2. Since I was using SCSS, added the below line in `src/styles.scss`

   ```
   @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
   ```
3. Add ng-localize

   ```
   ng add @angular/localize
   ```
4. Regarding the `NgbModule.forRoot()`, I can confirm that it is not required in newer versions of ng-bootstrap(I tried 8.0.0) as I have got bootstrap working in my angular project without it as shown below:

   file: app.module.ts

   ```js
   import {NgbModule.NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

   @NgModule({
     declarations:[AppComponent],
     imports: [NgbModule],
     providers: [],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })

   export class AppModule {
   }
   ```

---

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a compatibility issue between Angular, Bootstrap and NgBootstrap. Please ensure you're using the correct [dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap#dependencies) as per NgBootstraps documentation

Comment: Angular: 8.0.0  Bootstrap: 4.5.2  I installed ng bootstrap using "npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap", so the version should be the latest one which 8.0.0

Comment: That is clearly the issue, if you look at the table in the link above you'll see that for Angular 8 you need to use the latest build within version 5 (5.x.x means any version of 5) and use Bootstrap 4.3.1

Comment: Could you please tell me how to install ng bootstrap of version 5.x.x. I searched online and found if the angular version >= 9 then "ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" is used to install and installs the latest version. But How to install nb bootstrap of specific version 5.x.x

Comment: Use `npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@5.3.0` this is the current latest version under the 5.x.x umbrella